# Finding where the issue originates using stack trace (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stack-trace

I have a stack trace that I am getting via an e-mail through our error e-mail system.  However I am having problems recreating the error in my local environment, I know that I am having a null value error. I know I can use the stack trace to narrow down my search and how to recreate the error, but I don't think I am reading it right.

I think the problem is my Details page in my Customer Controller but I could be wrong.  Can anyone help translate this for me so I can find out where I can start?

```
2017-03-20 13:13:44,158 FATAL MainProgram.Controllers.CustomerController+<>c__DisplayClass8b - Exception propagated out of controller
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
   at MainProgram.Controllers.CustomerController.<>c__DisplayClass8b.<Details>b__50(Report i)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MainProgram.Controllers.CustomerController.<>c__DisplayClass8b.<Details>b__45(IGrouping`2 k)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MainProgram.Controllers.CustomerController.Details(String id)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Comment: Do you have any Linq expressions that are performing operations on nullable objects?  Make sure you're checking that those properties are not null (i.e. **HasValue**) before referencing the value.

Comment: Deploying *.pdb would help in future as then stacktraces will contain line numbers.